# Google play review rejected cause call log

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

[image]

I use `READ_SMS` and `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions in the merged `AndroidManifest.xml`.
But I do not use any permissions related to call log. Why was the review rejected?

I have checked the `AndroidManifest.xml` and all of the source code and I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot alone, it seems that in your privacy policy that you have attached to the project, you are missing an explanation about [READ_CALL_LOG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_CALL_LOG). If you have declared both the READ_SMS and the READ_PHONE_STATE, then somewhere in your application the READ_CALL_LOG is also declared and you need to disclose your usage with it.

Pay attention that for the READ_CALL_LOG permission:

> Note: If your app uses the READ_CONTACTS permission and both your
> minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values are set to 15 or lower, the
> system implicitly grants your app this permission. If you don't need
> this permission, be sure your targetSdkVersion is 16 or higher.

More information about declaring your app's data usage can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/declare-data-use#phone-number).